# Is there a bitmonero.conf file where I can hard code a --daemon-address for use when running monero-wallet-cli?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, bitmonero-conf

Is there a bitmonero.conf file where I can hard code a --daemon-address so I don't have to manually type it in every time I run the monero-wallet-cli?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no default wallet config file IIRC, so just put all your wallet specific settings in a file like `~/.bitmonero/wallet.conf` and then start your wallet like:

```
monero-wallet-cli --config-file ~/.bitmonero/wallet.conf
```

You can put any of the startup paremeters as listed from `monero-wallet-cli --help`. Just omit the leading `--` and place one option per line. So for your `daemon-address` it would look like:

```
daemon-address=node.moneroworld.com:18089
```