# Where is the monero conf file in the portable binaries version?

Tags: bitmonero-conf

The installation version has conf files [here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2866/where-are-the-monero-core-configuration-parameters-stored), but what if you unzipped the portable version from [here](https://downloads.getmonero.org/gui/win64)?
Does it not exist until created manually with `monerod --config-file=/etc/monerod.conf`? I installed the monero gui and even then no bitmonero.conf exists on my pc nor in the registry.

Answer (score 0):

You must create it yourself manually according to [this answer](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/11017/what-settings-to-put-in-bitcmonero-conf-file-to-default-to-using-a-public-remote?rq=1). I believe I remember bitcoin operating the same way.